# The parameter messaging_product is required." in MAKE integromat Whatsapp

Tags: http, makefile, whatsapp

I'm new to the Make enviroment. I'm trying to send a Whatsapp Message with this template.

```
Te dejamos tu numero de seguimiento: {{1}}
Recordá que para verificar su estado, tenés que ingresar a:
andreani.com
oca.com.ar
Tu numero de pedido es # {{2}} si necesitas hacer una consulta.
```

This is my code:

```
{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "to": "{{2.countryCallingCode}}{{2.phone}}",    "type": "template",
    "template": {
        "name": "ecommerce_delivery",
        "language": {
            "code": "es"
      },
    "components": [{
        "type": "body",
        "parameters": [{
            "type": "text",
            "text": "{{1.metaData[33].value}}"
                },{
            "type": "text",
            "text": "{{1.id}}"
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
```

When I test it, I get this.

```
"error":{"message":"(#100) The parameter messaging_product is required.","type":"OAuthException"
```

I can send the message with this code, but it just the template without variables.

```
{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "to": "543815462685",    "type": "template",
    "template": {
        "name": "hello_world",
        "language": {
            "code": "en_US"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you setup `header` or `buttons` in your template?

Comment: there is an API you can [retrieve the templates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/business-management-api/message-templates#retrieve-templates), can you please show that `ecommerce_delivery` template object in your question.